# Implementing Wide and Deep Neural Network using Functional API

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tf.keras

I am trying to build a Wide and Deep Neural Network using Keras Functional API. I am getting a value to shape mismatch error. I don't understand where I am wrong. I am implementing this on the Fashion MNIST dataset.The X_train shape is (60000,28,28) and Y_train is (60000,). I am guessing that the error is because of the line : input_ = keras.layers.... but I don't understand how to resolve it.

Code :

```
# Building a Non Sequnetial Model using Functional API One Use of it is in Wide and Deep Neural Networks
input_ = keras.layers.Input(shape=X_train.shape[1:])  # This will return shape of the input [28,28],remeber we dont have to set it to the number of neurons in the layer

hidden1 = keras.layers.Dense(100,activation = "relu")(input_)  # We have to call it as a function
hidden2 = keras.layers.Dense(100,activation = "relu")(hidden1)
concat_layer = keras.layers.concatenate([input_,hidden2])
output = keras.layers.Dense(10,activation="softmax")(concat_layer)
model = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_], outputs=[output])

model.compile(loss = keras.losses.sparse_categorical_crossentropy,optimizer = keras.optimizers.SGD(lr = 0.8),metrics= ["accuracy"])
Tensorboard_cb = keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(Path_Tensor)
model.fit(X_train,Y_train,validation_split=0.2,epochs=100,callbacks=[Tensorboard_cb])
```

Error :

```
Epoch 1/100
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-97-675a2b302d27> in <module>
----> 1 model.fit(X_train,Y_train,validation_split=0.2,epochs=100,callbacks=[Tensorboard_cb])

c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    106   def _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs):
    107     if not self._in_multi_worker_mode():  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 108       return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    109 
    110     # Running inside `run_distribute_coordinator` already.

c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1096                 batch_size=batch_size):
   1097               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1098               tmp_logs = train_function(iterator)
   1099               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1100                 context.async_wait()

c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    778       else:
    779         compiler = "nonXla"
--> 780         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    781 
    782       new_tracing_count = self._get_tracing_count()

c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    821       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    822       initializers = []
--> 823       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    824     finally:
    825       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    695     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
    696         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
--> 697             *args, **kwds))
    698 
    699     def invalid_creator_scope(*unused_args, **unused_kwds):

c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   2853       args, kwargs = None, None
   2854     with self._lock:
-> 2855       graph_function, _, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   2856     return graph_function
   2857 

c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3211 
   3212       self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3213       graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3214       self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3215       return graph_function, args, kwargs

c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3073             arg_names=arg_names,
   3074             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3075             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3076         self._function_attributes,
   3077         function_spec=self.function_spec,

c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    984         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    985 
--> 986       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
    987 
    988       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    598         # __wrapped__ allows AutoGraph to swap in a converted function. We give
    599         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
--> 600         return weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    601     weak_wrapped_fn = weakref.ref(wrapped_fn)
    602 

c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    971           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    972             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 973               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    974             else:
    975               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:806 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1211 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2585 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2945 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:789 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:749 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:149 __call__
        losses = ag_call(y_true, y_pred)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:253 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1567 sparse_categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4783 sparse_categorical_crossentropy
        labels=target, logits=output)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py:4176 sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2
        labels=labels, logits=logits, name=name)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:201 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    c:\users\na462\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\nn_ops.py:4091 sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits
        logits.get_shape()))

    ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (32, 1)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (32, 28, 10)).
```

Answer (score 1):

you forgot to add Flatten Layer, you input is 3D (None,28,28) but your output is only 2D (None,10), since you did not Flatten so you are getting (None, 28, 10) as out which is wrong.

also i think you did not use one hot encoding, because i can see (32,1) as your output shape rather then (32, 10). you need to change your last Dense layer neuron to 1, or use one hot encoding.

if you want to use Dense(1) then you have to make sure that your mnist dataset output is numeric, such as 0,1,2,3,4..9. but if you want to use Dense(10) then you have to use onehot encoding, your output will be [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] this is equal to 0 in decimal number system. [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] this is equal to 1 in decimal number system. it will have ten columns, each represent single decimal number, if a number in a column is 1 which mean it is that decimal number.

- 1st column mean 0, [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
- 2nd column mean 1  [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
- 3rd column mean 2  [0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
- so on
- last column mean 9 [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1]

as for flatten layer, if you input is image then image has width, height and color, which are 3 dimensions. but as you can see above your output is either a single number or 10 columns of 0`s and 1`s. in order to make 3 dimension in your 1 dimension output you have to use flatten layer.  also there is another hidden dimension which represent your data samples, or batch size. in your case it is 32. so your input is `(32, 28, 28)`. and your output is `(32, 10)`.

another thing is you can also use flatten layer first after you feed input. you can give input in the form of `(None, 784)` here `784` is `(28 multiple 28)`

Comment: Hi,thanks for your reply. I am new to keras and deep learning. SO please help me out. I studied everything from O'reilley book. I don't understand why to use flatten layer. I mean we need to provide the input shape of instance, that I can do by Flatten layer or Input layer. I used 10 in last layer because I am doing classification on MNIST with 10 classes.   refer : https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml2/blob/master/10_neural_nets_with_keras.ipynb Line [54] , he also used Input layer along with Dense(1) in end because of regression. Enlighten me what I am doing wrong :)

Comment: if you want to use Dense(1) then you have to make sure that your mnist dataset output is numeric, such as 0,1,2,3,4..9.  but if you want to use Dense(10) then you have to use onehot encoding, your output will be [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] this is equal to 0 in decimal number system. [0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0] this is equal to 1 in decimal number system.  it will have ten columns, each represent single decimal number, if a number in a column is 1 which mean it is that decimal number. 1st column mean 0, 2nd is 1, 3rd is 2 so on, last column is 9.

Comment: Could you please send the correct implementation for this problem so that I can understand Better. thanks